# Fastifyis not defined and fastify-postgres Fastify.pg.connect not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, fastify

I have defined my fastify like so:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({logger: true})

fastify
  .register(require('./setup/envs'))
  .after(async (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    fastify.register(require('./setup/db'))
    await fastify.after()
    
    fastify.register(require('./setup/jwt'))
    await fastify.after()

    fastify.register(require('./setup/auth'))
    await fastify.after()
    
    // load routes
    // fastify.register(require('./routes/test'))
    fastify.register(require('./routes/posts/index'), { prefix: '/posts' })
  })

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.ready()
    fastify.listen(3000)
  } catch (e) {
    fastify.log.error(e)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

start();
```

Now in my post routes, I have the following:

```
const postRoutes = require('../../controllers/posts');

async function PostRoutes(fastify, options) {
  fastify.addHook('preValidation', fastify.verifyJWT)
  fastify.addHook('preHandler', function (req, reply, done) {
    if (req.body) {
      req.log.info({ body: req.body }, 'parsed body')
    }
    if (req.params) {
      req.log.info({ params: req.body }, 'parsed params')
    }
    done()
  })

  // get all posts
  fastify.get('/:limit/:page', postRoutes.getPosts)

  fastify.post('/signup', async (req, reply) => {
    // some code
    const token = fastify.jwt.sign({ test: 'hello' })
    reply.send({ token })
  })

  fastify.get(
    "/test-auth",
    async function(request, reply) {
      return { test: 'auth' }
    }
  )
}

module.exports = PostRoutes;
```

and my controller file is the following:

```
const fastify = require('fastify');

const getPosts = async (req, reply) => {
  try {
    const client = await fastify.pg.connect()
    const { rows } = await client.query(
      'SELECT * FROM POSTS LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2;', [req.params.limit, req.params.offset],
    )
    client.release()
    return rows
  } catch (e) {
    req.log.error('Getting posts failed with params')
    throw new Error(e)
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getPosts,

};
```

The `const client = await fastify.pg.connect()` is giving me fastify is not defined and if I require it by adding `const fastify = require('fastify')` at the top, I get  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')`.

the following is my db.js:

```
const fastifyPlugin = require('fastify-plugin');
const fastifyPostgres = require('fastify-postgres');

async function dbConnector (fastify, options) {
  const dbUser = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_USERNAME)
  const dbPassword = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_PASSWORD);
  const dbHost = encodeURIComponent(process.env.DATABASE_HOST);
  const dbName = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_NAME);

  fastify.register(fastifyPostgres, {
    connectionString: `postgres://${dbUser}:${dbPassword}@${dbHost}/${dbName}`
  })
}
// Wrapping a plugin function with fastify-plugin exposes the decorators
// and hooks, declared inside the plugin to the parent scope.
module.exports = fastifyPlugin(dbConnector);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my route to

```
fastify.get('/:limit/:page', (req, reply) => postRoutes.getPosts(fastify, req, reply))
```

and then I was able to access the fastify object in my controller.